# Echarts - Is possible stack date bar from heightest to tallest?

Tags: echarts

[This is my actual state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUztx.png)

Is possible to stack date from the heightest to the tallest? like this:

[Objective state (stacked in the right order)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVVQy.png)

This is the code example to get my actual state:

```
series: [
    {
        name: 'teste1',
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '1',
        data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
        name: 'teste2',
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '1',
        data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
        name: 'teste3',
        type: 'bar',
        stack: '1',
        data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have two options:

1. Re-sort series data. The usual bar chart use data by horizontal but the stack bar use vertical column. Just arrange columns by ascending. Before: `120, 220, 150`, after: `120, 150, 220`.
2. Rebuild data with [dataset](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.encode), with dataset you can remap dimensions as you need.